# Laravel 5.1 use session to restrict direct access using urls users based on user role

Tags: laravel-5

I have 2 laravel projects, 1 for the front end where i m using html css angularjs. The second for api controllers. I call using http post and get the api controllers functions using angularjs to get content data.

In the front end i have a menu this menu appears differently based on user role, if admin or no.

This is done. My problem is the access for views using the url in the browser.

So I have a query where I get for each user what modules in the menu can he see. Now I'm putting the result in Laravel session.

```
$menu = DB::select menu by user id ... //Getting menu query based on user if admin or no

session(["menu" => $menu);
return session('menu');
```

I'm getting the results and the menu is showing good in the website based on the logged user if he s admin or no.

**Now, to solve the direct url access issue, I want to use this session and compare the url to this session, if the url exists in the session i will let him access, if no i will redirect him to somewhere.**
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest looking at the Laravel documentation on Authorization before going too far down a custom implementation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Without knowing more about how your front-end and back-end applications interact with each other, it is a little difficult to get into speciifics but i shall do my best.

Each page returned by Laravel has access to a `Request` object which contains information about the request which returned the page. You can access this `Request` and its assocaited `Route` using Laravels helper functions (if you are not passing it to the view already). The `getPrefix()` method will return the root relative url which you can then use as you see fit. For example:

```
// Return and store the URL as a string
$url = request()->route()->getPrefix();

// Check your session for the URL/s you want to allow and compare to the stored URL
if (session()->get('URL') == $url) {
    // User is allowed access to the page
    // Do something ...
} else {
    // User is not allowed access to this page
    // Redirect back or to a route of your choice
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I hope this gives you some ideas, good luck!